# How can I dynamically add the Google Maps API via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to use the Google Maps API on a page which I can only edit through an external javascript file. The problem is, when I try to load the Google Maps API dynamically using getScript, it doesn't load.

Is there any way to load the Google Maps API dynamically?

**This works:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2XVKL/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script>
function codeAddress() {

    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({'address':document.getElementById('address').value}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            alert('worked!');

        } 

    });

}
</script>

<body>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress()">
</body>
```

**But I need it the api to be dynamically loaded using only javascript, like this:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2XVKL/3/

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function () {

    $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false");

});


function codeAddress() {

    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({'address':document.getElementById('address').value}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            alert('worked!');

        } 

    });

}
</script>

<body>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress()">
</body>
```

**Edit: found the solution here - https://gist.github.com/jorgepedret/2432506**

Comment: That should be `$(document).ready`, without the double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch), you have to add `&callback=initialize` to your URL:

```
$.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dErNs/

---

To be completely safe, however, you should use `.done()` to make your function wait until the `.getScript()` is complete:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.gmap_async = $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize");
    // global Deferred variable
});

function codeAddress() {
    window.gmap_async.done(function () {
        new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({
            'address': document.getElementById('address').value
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                alert('worked!');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dErNs/1/